# Client shows all collections as empty

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am having trouble getting the client to find entries in a collection in a Meteor application.

This seems to be a common question and I have tried all the suggestions I have come across. For now, autopublish is included, so as far as I can tell the problem shouldn't be with publishing/subscribing.

I even went back and went through the simple-todo tutorial on meteor.com and meticulously checked each step. As soon as I replace my array with a collection, the collection comes up empty.

All I can think to do is wipe out my meteor install and reinstall, but I would really like to know what is causing this.

```js
printTypes = new Mongo.Collection("printTypes");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

Meteor.subscribe("printTypes");

Router.configure({
    loadingTemplate: 'homePage'
});

Router.map( function () {
    this.route('itemPage', {
        path: '/item',
        waitOn: function() {
            return Meteor.subscribe('printTypes');
        },
        data: function () {
            templateData = { printTypes: printTypes.find({}) };
            return templateData;
        }
    });
});
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
   Meteor.startup(function () {
     Meteor.publish("printTypes", function () {
     return printTypes.find();
     });
   });
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: hard to say without seeing your code

Comment: I have added the code in question.

Comment: that all looks fine. how did you check/see that the collection is empty?

Comment: After adding the homepage as the loading template, when the item page gets hit, it stays on that template indefinitely. This now makes me think the collection isn't return empty, but is not returning at all. Is there a better way to see if/when the collection is returning? This is making me feel like an idiot.

Comment: can you show us your `publish` code?

Comment: Sure. Added it. Thanks so much for spending so much time on this.

Comment: and I'm assuming `PrintTypes` vs `printTypes` is just a typo in the question?